# Bluestacks error: Failed to load channels. Unable to connect to the internet

Tags: android, emulation, bluestacks, channel

I keep getting this issue;

> Failed to load channels. Unable to connect to the internet.

When I try to load up bluestacks, I have tried numerous things such as using older versions and latest version of bluestacks, restarting, flushing DNS, using other DNS, using proxy and nothing seems to work.

I cannot use any other alternatives to bluestacks.

Specs: Windows 10 64bit Intel

Answer (score 1):

Try adding manually to the exception list from windows firewall.